# How to dynamically generate a pdf from Google's appengine?

Tags: google-app-engine, pdf-generation

I'd like to create an application that would run on Google's appengine.

However, this application needs to be able to generate PDFs dynamically.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the [`reportlab` library](http://www.reportlab.org/rl_toolkit.html) to generate a PDF from Python. You can just include the ReportLab files in with your application's code, or you can include a [zip archive](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/django10_zipimport.html) of the ReportLab code, and insert it into your application's `sys.path`.

Comment: Does reportlab actually work under AppEngine?  I was under the possibly-mistaken impression that it uses C extensions, which AppEngine doesn't allow.

Comment: Reportlab is pure Python, but it uses PIL for images, so you won't be able to use it for PDFs containing images.

Comment: GAE now supports PIL so that should not be a problem.

Comment: Does this actually work?  Reading the reportlab API, you seem to have to write to a file.  That's not possible on GAE.

Comment: You can write to any file-like object, meaning that you could write to, say, `response.out`.  For example, http://konryd.blogspot.com/2008/04/outputting-pdfs-with-google-app-engine.html

Comment: Thanks.  Note, I needed the fix referred to by @varun below

Comment: Just getting into this today, found a good primer by Nick Johnson on his blog http://blog.notdot.net/2010/04/Generating-PDFs-on-App-Engine-Python-and-introducing-Mapvelopes

Answer (score 7):

To overcome the number-of-files limit in google appengine, you could package your reportlib in a zip file and use it. Be sure you check out this issue i bumped into..

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1085

Also, you can use pisa, htmllib and pyPdf to generate the pdf using html templates.

All the best.

varun

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend **PyFPDF**, which is a pure-Python port of the lightweight yet highly powerful PHP FPDF library. It is hardly a few dozen kilobytes.

See http://code.google.com/p/pyfpdf/

Answer (score 3):

Google has a new "[Conversion API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/conversion/)" that may solve all your problems. Here's a description from the site:

> The App Engine Conversion API converts documents between common filetypes using Google's infrastructure for efficiency and scale. The API enables conversions between HTML, PDF, text, and image formats, synchronously or asynchronously, with an option to perform optical character recognition (OCR).

Comment: Looks like the Conversion API has been decommissioned.