# Convert HTML to PDF in python on Google App Engine

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, pdf-generation

I have had a look at this thread:

[How to dynamically generate a pdf from Google's appengine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327700/how-to-dynamically-generate-a-pdf-from-googles-appengine)

I know we can use ReportLab, however, I am not sure how i can give it a HTML file and get a PDF.

Basically, HTML in and PDF out

Answer (score 2):

if you can use an external lib, there is [xhtml2pdf](http://www.xhtml2pdf.com/)

Comment: Can't do that. As i want everything to run on app engine only.

Comment: btw, will this pickup embedded images in the html file by itself?

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [html-2-pdf.com](http://html-2-pdf.com)

It's build in top of: [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)

It's really easy to use it. It's stand-alone so just upload a file on your (Linux) system and you are ready to produce PDFs

Comment: Awesome! I don't think i can use this in appengine directly though but i am very happy with the rendering engine! the PDF was exactly the same as the web page! nicely done.

Answer (score 0):

xhtml2pdf states that the source is pure python. you should be able to use this as a module in your application.