# Web server which generates PDF files

Tags: python, http, pdf, web-applications, latex

I'm building a website using Python which uses LaTeX to generate PDF files. But I want to put most of the website on Google App Engine, and I can't run LaTeX on that. So I want to do the LaTeX part on another server.

It seemed like a simple problem at first---I thought the best way to do it would be to POST the LaTeX to the server and have it respond with the PDF. But LaTeX files can take a while to compile sometimes if they're long, so I'm starting to think this isn't the best way to do it. What's the standard way of doing something like this? It must be a pretty common problem.

Comment: This has basically been [asked before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327700/how-to-dynamically-generate-a-pdf-from-googles-appengine). In essence, use ReportLab.

Comment: Actually, I specifically want to use LaTeX, not ReportLab. But that does look like a nice library to keep in mind for other projects!

Comment: Submit the LaTeX to the remote web server, which returns a job handle. Then you can poll another URL on the server, and ask whether job X is done yet. When it is, make a request to the PDF retrieval URL, specifying the job handle. You'll probably want to wrap authentication around it all as well, so servers can only retrieve jobs that they themselves submitted.

Answer (score 0):

can you send it by email just like amazon , send a file to server , when it's ok , the server send it by email